# Laravel database session driver doesn't store in session table

Tags: session, laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to use the database Session driver in laravel 4.2.

I've changed the `driver` setting in my `config/session.php` to `database` and created the `session` database table via artisan.

To test it out, I used `php artisan tinker` to set some session information:

```
Session::put('test', 'worked');
// NULL
Session::get('test');
// 'worked'
```

Everything is working as expected. The problem is when I look at the sessions table in the database there are no records.

I read through the docs for [Session](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/session) and I don't think I missed anything. Was there something else I was supposed to change?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try calling Session::save() and seeing if it shows up in the db then?

Comment: Hmm, no I hadn't. I'll give that a try tonight. Thanks for the reply!